# Multer in Node Js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, web-deployment, multer

I am trying to use multer module in my website but my doubt is that we are declaring upload as constant `const upload =multer({});` but then in the post method, we are using upload `(req,res,error)` method is it the same object or a different one. Can someone please help me out it would be a great help.

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits:{fileSize: 1000000},
  fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  }
}).single('myImage');`

`app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if(err){
      res.render('index', {
        msg: err
      });
    } else {
      if(req.file == undefined){
        res.render('index', {
          msg: 'Error: No File Selected!'
        });
      } else {
        res.render('index', {
          msg: 'File Uploaded!',
          file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}`
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The upload is defined as object but in the post method we are defining a method

Comment: Same object with what?

Comment: I have edited the post I have added the code.Can you please check it out

Comment: Hi @doj. Welcome to SO. `multer.single()` is an express middleware. Middleware has the definition `(req, res, nxt)`. In the `const` statement, you are returned a function matching that definition. That being said, this code looks right. Have you encountered an error?

Comment: Thank You I have now understood the concept